# How do I create a file and mount it as a filesystem?

Tags: mount, filesystem

How do I create a file of size 10M, format it with ext3 filesystem and then mount it in /media/fuse?

I tried with

```
mkfs -t ext3 file
```

then to mount it

```
mount -t ext3 file /media/fuse
```

It didn't work because it said that file wasn't a block device. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You just have to add `-o loop` to the mount command.

Comment: A great tutorial here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/

Comment: To loop-mount a ISO file, I do this `mount -o loop file.iso /media/iso`.

Comment: @enzotib Can you post that as an answer to be upvoted/accepted  please?

Comment: @TomBrossman: done

Comment: For completeness, I had to specify the size when creating the filesystem file, like this: `mkfs -t ext4 file 10240` This will create a file system with a size of 10 MB.

Comment: Looks like @arrange's link is now [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-linux-filesystem/)

Answer (score 22):

Your procedure is correct, but when mounting a file image as a filesystem you have to add the `-o loop` option to the `mount` command:

```
mount -t ext3 -o loop file /media/fuse
```

Also, the `-t ext3` option is not strictly required, because `mount` can automatically determine the filesystem type.

Comment: he is right but forgot to add the way to create a file `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1024 count=10240` this is the way to create a 10Mb file... then you can format it with `mkfs.ext3`

Comment: Now `mount` does not need the `-o loop` option anymore, it can understand by itself we it need it.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the top answer with further explanation of why this is (was) needed: `mount` operates on block devices.  To the kernel, a file is not a block device.  It can become a block device, however, by configuring a loop device to use it as backing.  This is what you're doing with `-o loop`.  In recent times loop device handling is a lot easier: since kernel 2.6.35 loop devices set up during mount are now destroyed automatically when unmounted, and the mount command can automatically set up a loop device with just `-o loop` instead of specifying a particular loop device.

Comment: And as other comments state, recently mount is smart enough to do the loop setup transparently without even `-o loop`

Answer (score 10):

I tried to apply the steps and comments from the previous answer.
It still took some work to figure it out, so I've added another answer for people after me.

The following procedure creates a local file named `file` and mounts it on a local directory named `mounted_file`.

1. Create a fixed size file with e.g.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1000 count=100
   ```

   which creates a file of 100 times 1000 bytes (100 kB) filled with zeroes.
2. Format it with the desired file system, create a directory, mount it, and get permission to use it (owner is root):

   ```
   mkfs.ext3 file
   mkdir mounted_file/
   sudo mount -o loop file mounted_file/
   sudo chmod -R 777 mounted_file/
   ```

   The `-o loop` parameter is optional nowadays.
3. To clean up afterwards:

   ```
   sudo umount mounted_file/
   rmdir mounted_file/
   rm file
   ```

Use `mkfs.ext3 -n file` to see the details of the file system that will created. If desired e.g. the block size (`-b block-size`) and number of inodes (`-N number-of-inodes`) can be changed.

Note that we can also run out of inodes (total number of files and directories) instead of diskspace, which is usually not clearly communicated.

Comment: i get an error `Not enough space to build proposed filesystem while setting up superblock` on `mkfs.ext3 file`, i've created the file with dd, adding more in size doesn't do anything

Comment: nevermind, the file didn't end in .fs

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer using `truncate -s 10M filename` (then mkfs) because truncate expands dynamically unlike fallocate or dd and can also be resized larger (or smaller) without damaging data with losetup and resize2fs. And of course it can be mounted as a filesystem.

See here for more detail: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698656/346155