# how to open and see content of ext2 file in Ubuntu

Tags: disk

I have a file root.ext2 in a iso file. How can I  open and see content of ext2 file in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and mount it as a filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85977)

Comment: @ignis 
Thank you for the link. Though all my searching I couldn't meet such an answer. That't why askubuntu is handy.